# Import img in ReactJS Components without save it locally (as a file)

Tags: reactjs, webpack

```
<img src={BASENAME+"/src/images/cabecera_CE.jpg"} id="idImgCabecera" alt="Universidad Politécnica de Cartagena" class="img-responsive"/>
```

and I want next:

```
import PHOTO from './../images/cabecera_CE.jpg'

<img src={PHOTO}/>
```

OR

```
<img src={require("./../images/cabecera_CE.jpg")} />
```

But it is not working... Also happen in a `index.html` file. I have next:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="/upct/src/images/icono.ico"/>
```

and I want next:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href={require("./src/images/icono.ico"/)}>
```

I have achieved that but my img is copied into my public folder with name `5465452465.jpg`. I wanna try without saving them into public (as url-loader does). How could I solve this?. Do I need any special plugin for webpack to do this?

Comment: there is no meaning of this path: `./../images/cabecera_CE.jpg`, if it start with `.` then `..` should not come in the middle, or it should only contain `..` no `.`, check the path again and meaning of these `.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must configure your [url-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/url-loader), which uses [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader) internally.
In order not to get hashed file names just leave `[path][name].[ext]` parameters. Omit the `[hash]` template.

```
{
    test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
    loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000',
    options: {
        name: '[path][name].[ext]'
    }
}
```

With this configuration images smaller than 10000 bytes will be inlined as [Data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs). If you want to disable this behavior, then just use raw file-loader.

Your assets will land in the root by default, however, you can change the `publicPath`, for example, to '/images/' in your output configuration section:

```
output: {
    ...
    path: buildPath,
    publicPath: '/images/'
}
```

---

Relative paths suck most of the time, you can configure Webpack, so you can import modules relative to your src folder by using this:

```
resolve: {
    modules: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        'node_modules'
    ]
},
```

Then you can import modules:

```
import PHOTO from 'images/cabecera_CE.jpg'

<img src={PHOTO} />
```

Better, isn't it?

Comment: Thank you! It is working on src/Components... But in index.html how can do that? I remove loader: `'?limit=10000',` from `loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000',` due to I do not want save img in local files. But I do not know how can I implement that on index.html. Thank you.

Comment: You can generate index.html file on your own as the default Webpack config doesn't allow for this, even with [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin). However, you can create a static template with direct links and use [transfer-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/transfer-webpack-plugin) to copy the static assets to the output directory. For example: <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="/icono.ico"/>. In the /src/www folder you put the icono.ico and in plugins sections: `new TransferWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'www' }], path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')),`.

Comment: Yes, you can remove the limit but be aware of performance implications - your resources will be inlined and bigger by about 33% and cannot be downloaded in parallel. Use this only to download small or required assets. For other assets please use classic approach.

Comment: Ok! Thank you. But I wanna do that icono.ico was loaded with url-loader or similar (I mean, do not stay statically in my project, if not as you say, is hosted in a url). Is that possible? Thank you for all your help.

Comment: You can manually [convert that icon to data-uri](https://websemantics.uk/tools/image-to-data-uri-converter/) and insert it to your index.html. Otherwise, you are left with index.html generation on your own or using transfer plugin. This is a great idea for a Webpack module that instead of using simple template would allow using all the code features, requires, imports, etc...

Comment: Thank you! I am using `copy-webpack-plugin` that it is as `transfer-webpack-plugin`. I saw your link of data-uri but... I must copy that link on `link href´ import? There is any way to get that data-uri with some plugin or similar?. Thank you again.

Comment: `copy-webpack-plugin` looks like `transfer-webpack-plugin` so it's ok. You can use data-uris where you would normally use href attribute so for example: <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="data:image/x-icon;base64,AAABAAUAEBAAAAEAIABoBAAAVgAAABgYAAABACAAiAkAAL4EAAAgIAAAAQAgAKgQAABGDgAAMDAAAAEAIACoJQAA7h4AAEBAAAABACAAKEIAAJZEAAAoAAAAEAAAACAAAAABACAAAA..." />  but see how simple icon is huge! You should really consider static urls for icons and just use those transfer plugins.